# Put firebase data in a JTable

Tags: java, firebase, swing, firebase-realtime-database, jtable

I am struggling to put some firebase data into a jtable in java swing.
As seen in photo I've been able to retrieve the data from firebase but for some reason the data won't be displayed in the JTable field(table1)
I looks like the getID(), getName()... methods didn't get any value, since I tried to print row[i] to see if there is any value.

[There is a screenshot of the actual program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3O59.png)

Could any of you tell what's the problem?

```
addNewCaseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                ref = database.getReference("NewCases");
                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());

                        ArrayList<Object[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
                        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table1.getModel();
                        tableModel.addColumn("ID");
                        tableModel.addColumn("Name");
                        tableModel.addColumn("Age");
                        tableModel.addColumn("City");
                        tableModel.addColumn("TimeStamp");
                        tableModel.addColumn("Disease");
                        tableModel.addColumn("Risk");
                        Object[] row = new Object[6];
                        tableModel.setNumRows(0);
                        myList.clear();

                        CasesList casesList = new CasesList();

              for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            

               casesList.setID((Integer)ds.child("ID").getValue());
                      
               casesList.setName(ds.child("Name").getValue().toString());
                            
               casesList.setAge((Integer)ds.child("Age").getValue());
                            
               casesList.setCity(ds.child("City").getValue().toString());
                            
          
         casesList.setTimeStamp(ds.child("TimeStamp").getValue().toString());
                            
         casesList.setDisease(ds.child("Disease").getValue().toString());
                            
         casesList.setRisk(ds.child("Risk").getValue().toString());
//       myList.add(ds.getKey());

                            row[0] = casesList.getID();
                            row[1] = casesList.getName();
                            row[2] = casesList.getAge();
                            row[3] = casesList.getCity();
                            row[4] = casesList.getTimeStamp();
                            row[5] = casesList.getDisease();
                            row[6] = casesList.getRisk();
                            myList.add(row);

                            System.out.println(myList);
                            tableModel.addRow(row);
                        }
                        table1.setModel(tableModel);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"There is a screenshot of the actual program"* Show the code of an actual [mre].

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I put the code now

Comment: Forget about your database. First create an empty TableModels with just the columns names. Then add a row of hardcoded data to the model and the model to the table. Then make sure the table is displayed on the frame. This will demonstrate that you know how to use a JTable. If you have trouble then you post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. We can't test your code since we don't have access to your databse. Then once this basic program works you add the logic to get the data from the database. Do problem solving one step at a time to isolate where the problem is.

Comment: I've finally been able to print the data in the JTable, but it shows only one row instead of three! Do you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you defined the table columns with lines like these?

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
tableModel.addColumn("ID");
tableModel.addColumn("Name");
tableModel.addColumn("Age");
```

Also, the method `setModel` should be called after the for:

```
  for... {
      //add row to tableModel 
  }
  table1.setModel(tableModel);
```

**EDIT:**
Analyzing in more detail, I also verify that you have 7 fields but your array has only space for 6. In this line `row [6] = casesList.getRisk ();` throws an exception at runtime. Expand the size of your array to solve this.
`Object[] row = new Object[7];`

To display the column names it is convenient to add your table to a scroll panel.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table1);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

This works for me:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table1.getModel();
tableModel.addColumn("ID");
tableModel.addColumn("Name");
tableModel.addColumn("Age");
tableModel.addColumn("City");
tableModel.addColumn("TimeStamp");
tableModel.addColumn("Disease");
tableModel.addColumn("Risk");
Object[] row = new Object[7];
tableModel.setNumRows(0);
myList.clear();


for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    
    CasesList casesList = new CasesList();
    casesList.setID((Integer) ds.child("ID").getValue());
    casesList.setName(ds.child("Name").getValue().toString());
    casesList.setAge((Integer) ds.child("Age").getValue());
    casesList.setCity(ds.child("City").getValue().toString());
    casesList.setTimeStamp(ds.child("TimeStamp").getValue().toString());
    casesList.setDisease(ds.child("Disease").getValue().toString());
    casesList.setRisk(ds.child("Risk").getValue().toString());

    row[0] = casesList.getID();
    row[1] = casesList.getName();
    row[2] = casesList.getAge();
    row[3] = casesList.getCity();
    row[4] = casesList.getTimeStamp();
    row[5] = casesList.getDisease();
    row[6] = casesList.getRisk();
    
    myList.add(row);

    System.out.println(myList);
    tableModel.addRow(row);
    
}
table1.setModel(tableModel);
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. It still does show the result in the console but not in JTable

Comment: Thank you :) 
It seems like I forgot to get the value of a field from firebase lol, that's why Object[6] threw exception at runtime.